# RNA warning on EnumProperty

Tags: python, properties

I create some lists using EnumProperty. The lists may be empty, because nothing in the lists. Therefore, I get some warning in the console.
**"RNA Warning: Current value "0" matches no enum in......."**
How to get rid of the warning in the console?
I don't want to add some "NONE" in the lists when the lists are empty.

Comment: AFAIK enum props are expected to have at least one element.  Are they dynamic enums? what is the issue with having a dummy 'NONE' enum when empty?

Comment: Yes, they are dynamic enums. I am using an add-on makehuman. They also have the enums, but they don't show rna warning when the enums are empty. I don't know why my code have rna warning. @batFINGER

Comment: Do you have any UI code accessing the empty enums?

Comment: Yes. I create some buttons to import the object on the list. @batFINGER

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid this problem by adding a dummy to the list e.g. `'NONE'` which will be used if there is nothing else to draw. This way you can also detect if the list is actually drawn/used for the UI:

```
("NONE", "None", "", 1),
("RED", "Red", "", 2),
("GREEN", "Green", "", 3),
("BLUE", "Blue", "", 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the length of the dynamic list,
This error occurs, when the index is not found in the list
Example -

```py
("NONE", "None", "", 1), # <--- Not start with 0
("RED", "Red", "", 2),
("GREEN", "Green", "", 3),
("BLUE", "Blue", "", 4)
```

#### Solution

If you fist display `Blue` with 4 index.
Keep the index with `Blue` even if index 3 is no longer present

```py
("NONE", "None", "", 1),
("BLUE", "Blue", "", 4) # <--- index 4
```

Otherwise, you will get error:

```py
("NONE", "None", "", 1),
("BLUE", "Blue", "", 2) # <--- index 2
pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '4' matches no enum in 'Scene'
```

Note :- We can't change enum active index without property assignment