# The system command line prompts for a WARN, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, node-editor, command-line

```
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.002', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.002', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.003', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.003', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.001', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.001', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.004', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.004', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.006', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.006', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.005', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.005', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.002', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.002', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.003', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.003', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.001', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.001', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.004', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.004', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.006', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.006', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.005', 'type'
WARN (bpy.rna): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v330\blender.git\source\blender\python\intern\bpy_rna.c:1340 pyrna_enum_to_py: current value '712' matches no enum in 'Node', 'Separate RGB.005', 'type'
```

Comment: How do you expect anyone to know how you produce this warning without any supporting info? Did you even google? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109321/rna-warning-on-enumproperty

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in addition to complete lack of effort in communicating the problem, it also seems to be about building Blender and that is off-topic.

Comment: Hello. lee. We have absolutely no context here. No clue to what activity produced this warning, Please imagine what it would be like to be handed this text on a piece of paper, and asked to solve the problem, yourself. I'm afraid, anyway, Martynas is right. BSE can help you with the normal use of the application and its shipped add-ons, but not with building it. Sorry, but without further context, this uestion has to be called off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Separate RGB` nodes are `Undefined` that's why you are getting these warnings.

I guess you are opening a blend file made in 3.2 in 3.3 or vice-versa.

In 3.3 + there is a `Separate Color` node

[image]

In 3.2 and lower there is a `Separate RGB` node

[image]

Comment: YES, I think it should be some material ball, so how do I fix it instead? Delete those nodes?  But how do I find them?

Comment: thank you，you‘re right，I found these nodes. And deleting them solves the problem